# How would I change the rails project directory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

I am using Ruby on Windows and when I use rails to create a project it puts the folder in my user directory, I'd like to specify another location. How would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify a full path when you say `rails new`:

```
> rails new /some/path/where/you/want/your/app
```

That should work in Windows just like everywhere else.

You can always say `rails --help` or `rails command --help` to get some quick help on using the `rails` command.

Comment: Thank you so much, that's the answer I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

use `cd` to move to the directory you want it in before generating the project.